# How to add checkbox or radio buttons to a Unity quicklist?

Tags: unity, python, application-development, quicklists

I have been searching how to make that happen but i can't find it anywhere. I even guessed how to enable/disable the quicklist item, so as how to add function invoked after the item is clicked, but that's all. Any ideas?

I want to make a quicklist for my app which will consist of checkboxes or radio buttons. I found info how to add items without associated action to the quicklist ([tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/launcher/)) but that's all I found, there is no information how to add other types of items (checkboxes, radio buttons, horizontal dividers or item with associated action) which are mentioned there.
I'm trying to get something like [this](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/73268718/quicklist.png).

Comment: I could not understand the question properly. Can you please tell what you are trying to achieve(a GUI or a item within the program)?

Comment: By item i meant an entry displayed after right click on the unity launcher, so yes, it's GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure is it correct, but I'm using something like this:

- checkbox:

```
def check_item_activated_callback (menuitem, a, b):
    if menuitem.property_get_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE) == Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_CHECKED:
       menuitem.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_UNCHECKED)
    else:
       menuitem.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_CHECKED)

check1 = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ()
check1.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, "Checkbox")
check1.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_TYPE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_CHECK)
check1.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_CHECKED)
check1.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)
check1.connect (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_SIGNAL_ITEM_ACTIVATED, check_item_activated_callback, None)
qucklist.child_append (check1)
```

- radio buttons:

```
def radio_item_activated_callback (radioitem1, a, radioitem2):
    radioitem1.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_CHECKED)
    radioitem2.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_UNCHECKED)

radio1 = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ()
radio1.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, "Radio Button 1")
radio1.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_TYPE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_RADIO)
radio1.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_UNCHECKED)
radio1.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)
quicklist.child_append (radio1)

radio2 = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new()
radio2.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, "Radio Button 2")
radio2.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_TYPE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_RADIO)
radio2.property_set_int (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_CHECKED)
radio2.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)
quicklist.child_append (radio2)

radio1.connect (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_SIGNAL_ITEM_ACTIVATED, radio_item_activated_callback, radio2)
radio2.connect (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_SIGNAL_ITEM_ACTIVATED, radio_item_activated_callback, radio1)
```

- separator (aka "horizontal dividers"):

```
separator = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ();
separator.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TYPE, Dbusmenu.CLIENT_TYPES_SEPARATOR)
separator.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)
quicklist.child_append (separator)
```

- enabled/disabled menu items:

```
item1 = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ()
item1.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, "Item Enabled")
item1.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)
item1.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_ENABLED, True)
quicklist.child_append (item1)

item2 = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ()
item2.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, "Item Disabled")
item2.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)
item2.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_ENABLED, False)
quicklist.child_append (item2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of making a Checkbox type Quicklist menu item:

```
    # Create toggle-able menu item for urgency
    urgent_menu_item = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ()

    # Set the tab's name as the menu item's name
    urgent_menu_item.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, _('Urgent'))

    # Make the menu item toggle-able
    urgent_menu_item.property_set(Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_TYPE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_CHECK)
    urgent_menu_item.property_set_int(Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_STATE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_STATE_UNCHECKED)
    urgent_menu_item.connect('item_activated', self.urgent_menu_item_activated)

    # Make the menu item visible
    urgent_menu_item.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)

    # Add the section's menu item to the Quicklist menu
    quicklist.child_append(urgent_menu_item)
```

And here is one for making a Radio type Quicklist menu item:

```
        # Create a new item for this section
        section_menu_item = Dbusmenu.Menuitem.new ()

        # Set the tab's name as the menu item's name
        section_menu_item.property_set (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, tab_name)

        # Make the menu item toggle-able
        section_menu_item.property_set(Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_TOGGLE_TYPE, Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_TOGGLE_RADIO)

        # Make the menu item visible
        section_menu_item.property_set_bool (Dbusmenu.MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, True)

        # When the menu item is clicked, make it call menu_item_activated
        # with the tab id, which is used to make that the active tab
        section_menu_item.connect('item_activated', self.section_menu_item_activated, tab_id)

        # Add the section's menu item to the Quicklist menu
        quicklist.child_append(section_menu_item)
```